# Making two functions run seperatly after another in Java

Tags: java, android, synchronization, android-animation

I have an animation and an intent which should be triggered. But the intent should be triggered only after the animation has ended. I have tried using synchronized statement, but I must be doing something wrong.
Is there a way to make the threads wait until my animation has ended?

Code:

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            synchronized (startButton){
                animate();
                buttonClick();}
        }
    });




}
public synchronized void animate (){
    final ImageButton startButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    final Animation bewegen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.bewegen);
    startButton.startAnimation(bewegen);
}

public synchronized void buttonClick(){
    Intent viewStartseite = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Startseite.class);
    //ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(startButton, 0,
    //        0, startButton.getWidth(), startButton.getHeight());
    startActivity(viewStartseite);
}
```

Comment: You can add an animation listener and then call buttonClick function in onAnimationEnd() method.

Comment: This worked easily thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `synchronized` key word in java is used for functions that only one thread can execute at a time. It has nothing to do with Async tasks. Your problem is that starting the animation starts a new thread. The main thread will then continue with the `buttonClick()` while the animation takes place.

You can try using:

```
.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                 buttonClick();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```